# insert object into a set

Tags: c++

I want to insert a vector into a set like this:

```
set<vector<prmEdge> > cammini;
vector<prmEdge> vecEdge;
cammini.insert(vecEdge);
```

I have a compilation error like this:

```
prmPlanner.cpp:1285:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:853: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__first1.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = const prmEdge*, _Container = std::vector<prmEdge, std::allocator<prmEdge> >]() < __first2.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = const prmEdge*, _Container = std::vector<prmEdge, std::allocator<prmEdge> >]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:855: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__first2.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = const prmEdge*, _Container = std::vector<prmEdge, std::allocator<prmEdge> >]() < __first1.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = const prmEdge*, _Container = std::vector<prmEdge, std::allocator<prmEdge> >]()’
make[1]: *** [prmPlanner.o] Errore 1
```

What should I do?
Could somebody help me??

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't know how to compare vectors. You should supply `operator<` for `vector<prmEdge>` (or for `prmEdge` to automatically use `std::lexicographical_compare` for vectors) or use `unordered_set` if you don't actually need sorted set of vectors.

Comment: But there is a non-member operator<() defined for vector: http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/vector.html#idx1350.  Shouldn't that work?

Comment: how to declare a set with unordered_set?

Comment: @Fred Larson, it uses `std::lexicographical_compare` for comparing, so should be defined `operator<` for `prmEdge`.

Comment: @Kirill: Ah, I understand. It's not vector that needs operator<() defined, it's prmEdge. Thank you.

Comment: @livio8495, `unordered_set` is not part of current standard, but it supported in most popular compilers. You could use `boost::unordered_set` as alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Since the elements in your `set` are `vector`s, which don't define `operator<`, you'll need to do one of two things: write a wrapper around `vector` that defines `operator<`, or else write a comparison functor, and supply it as a parameter when you create your set.

Answer (score 0):

The object contained in the set must have `operator <` defined.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` needs its entries to be sortable. The `std::vector` is however not sortable.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` needs a predicate to sort elements. By default that's `<`, so you would need to define `operator <` for `vector<prmEdge>`. You can supply a custom predicate to `std::set` as well, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8wh7665(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

agree with previous answers, just want to add that you can create global `bool operator<(vector<T> v)`